"ValueError: unsupported format character 'I' (0x49) at index 34" in Python LaTeX generation
I’m trying to generate a LaTeX document using Python. Here’s my code:
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string


latex_document = ""

for counter in range(1, 301):  
    
    # Random parameters for the function
    k = random.randint(2, 9)
    x0 = random.choice([i for i in range(1, 9) if i != 0])
    y0 = random.choice([i for i in range(1, 9) if i != 0])
    
    # Initialize the LaTeX document
    latex_document += r"""
    % Positioning of the string of zeros in the top-right corner
    \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(17cm, 1cm) % Modify position and size as needed
    \textbf{000""" + str(counter) + r"""}
    \end{textblock*}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \large{{\bf Name of the class}}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    {\bf November 29, 2026 }\\[.2cm]
    Name of the teacher \\[1ex]
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Surname, Name, Student ID .........................................................................
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \normalsize
    
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Write the function
    \[
    f(x, y) = \sqrt{{%d - (x - %d)^2 - (y - %d)^2}} + \frac{1}{x - %d}
    \]   
    """ % (k, x0, y0)
    # Close the document
    latex_document += r"""
    \end{enumerate}"""

# Save the LaTeX document to a file
with open('quiz.tex', 'w') as f:
    f.write(latex_document)

print("LaTeX document generated and saved as 'quiz.tex'.")

When I run it, I get this error:
ValueError: unsupported format character 'I' (0x49) at index 34

I suspect it has something to do with how I’m formatting the string, but I can’t figure out why. How can I fix this issue?

Literal Percent symbols % must be entered twice to be escaped when performing percent string format.
% Positioning should be %% Positioning
% Modify      should be %% Modify
import random
import string


latex_document = ""

for counter in range(1, 301):  
    
    # Random parameters for the function
    k = random.randint(2, 9)
    x0 = random.choice([i for i in range(1, 9) if i != 0])
    y0 = random.choice([i for i in range(1, 9) if i != 0])
    
    # Initialize the LaTeX document
    latex_document += r"""
    %% Positioning of the string of zeros in the top-right corner
    \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(17cm, 1cm) %% Modify position and size as needed
    \textbf{000%s}
    \end{textblock*}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \large{{\bf Name of the class}}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    {\bf November 29, 2026 }\\[.2cm]
    Name of the teacher \\[1ex]
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Surname, Name, Student ID .........................................................................
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \normalsize

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Write the function
    \[
    f(x, y) = \sqrt{{%d - (x - %d)^2 - (y - %d)^2}} + \frac{1}{x - %d}
    \]
    """ % (str(counter),k, x0, y0, y0)
    # Close the document
    latex_document += r"""
    \end{enumerate}"""

print(latex_document)

Showing only first iteration
    % Positioning of the string of zeros in the top-right corner
    \begin{textblock*}{2cm}(17cm, 1cm) % Modify position and size as needed
    \textbf{0001}
    \end{textblock*}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \large{{\bf Name of the class}}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    {\bf November 29, 2026 }\\[.2cm]
    Name of the teacher \\[1ex]
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Surname, Name, Student ID .........................................................................
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \normalsize

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Write the function
    \[
    f(x, y) = \sqrt{{7 - (x - 1)^2 - (y - 8)^2}} + \frac{1}{x - 8}
    \]
    
    \end{enumerate}

